# angular 4 with ng-sidebar, add class right

Tags: javascript, angular

Im using [ng-sidebar](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar#readme) on my angular 4 project, but i dont know where to put the "ng-sidebar--right" class, can you guys help me with this litle problem (im newbie, sorry). my code looks like this:

app.component.html:

```
<ng-sidebar-container>
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</ng-sidebar>

<div ng-sidebar-content>
    <router-outlet>
        <div class="jumbotron header">
            <img src="../assets/img/logo.png">
            <button type="button" class="menu" (click)="_toggleSidebar()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    public _opened: boolean = false;
    public _toggleSidebar() {
        this._opened = !this._opened;
    }
}
```

thanks for your time! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the sidebar on the right side you have to set the `position` input to "right":

```
<!-- A sidebar -->
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" position="right">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</ng-sidebar>
```

If you want to style it you can use the predefined classes in your CSS. For the right sidebar there's the class "ng-sidebar--right":

```
.ng-sidebar--right {
    color: red;
    background: antiquewhite;
    width: 12rem;
 }
```

I created a stackblitz example for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-sidebar